# Uploading files above 50KB via WCF service fails

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, azure

I am trying to get a file upload/download via a WCF service working. The transfer protocol is HTTP. I have set the binding up to user `Streaming` as transfer mode and have tried for days now to get it working properly, without success. I have managed to get it working for small files. When uploading large files, the file is created on the server, a number of bytes are written and then the transaction fails.

The service is hosted in a Windows Azure WebRole environment scaled to a degree which must definitely be sufficient for the task.

When inspecting the trace log with (e2e-file) with SvcTraceViewer.exe, the problem seems to be this:

> An exception has been thrown when reading the stream.

with the call stack:

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.MessageBodyStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
DataService.TransferService.UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
SyncInvokeUploadImage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

The service contract looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{
    [OperationContract]
    RemoteFileInfo DownloadImage(DownloadRequest request);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void UploadImage(RemoteFileInfo request);
}

[MessageContract]
public class DownloadRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string FileName;
}

[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)] 
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)] 
    public long Length;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)] 
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the service implementation:

```
public class TransferService : ITransferService
{
    public RemoteFileInfo DownloadImage(DownloadRequest request)
    {
        return DownloadFile(request);            
    }

    public void UploadImage(RemoteFileInfo request)
    {            
        UploadFile(request);
    }

    public RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request)
    {
        var result = new RemoteFileInfo();
        try
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("TempStorage").RootPath, request.FileName);
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

            if (!fileInfo.Exists)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", request.FileName);

            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            result.FileName = request.FileName;
            result.Length = fileInfo.Length;
            result.FileByteStream = stream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
    {
        FileStream targetStream;
        var sourceStream = request.FileByteStream;

        var filePath = Path.Combine(RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("TempStorage").RootPath, request.FileName);

        using (targetStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            const int bufferLen = 65000;
            var buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
            var count = 0;
            while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
            {
                targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            targetStream.Close();
            sourceStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I've set the web.config of the WCF service up like this to enable streaming, increase the relevant size limitations (or at least the ones I know of) and the timeouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            name="AzureDiagnostics">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "log.e2e" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" executionTimeout="14400"   />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                 transferMode="Streamed" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The client side is a WPF application. The calling code is this:

```
private void UploadImage(byte[] data, Guid guid)
{
    using (var transferService = new TransferServiceClient())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var uploadRequestInfo = new RemoteFileInfo();
        uploadRequestInfo.FileName = guid.ToString();
        uploadRequestInfo.Length = data.Length;
        uploadRequestInfo.FileByteStream = stream;
        transferService.UploadImage(uploadRequestInfo);
    }
}

private byte[] DownloadImage(Guid guid)
{
    using (var transferService = new TransferServiceClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new DownloadRequest(guid.ToString());
            var iconFile = transferService.DownloadImage(request);
            var data = ByteArrayOperations.FromStream(iconFile.FileByteStream);
            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and - finally - the client side app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>      

  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097150"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>           
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" 
                 closeTimeout="04:01:00"
                 openTimeout="04:01:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="04:10:00" 
                 sendTimeout="04:01:00"
                 allowCookies="false" 
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 messageEncoding="Text" 
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                    proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

      <endpoint address="xxx/TransferService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService"
                contract="Transfer.ITransferService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Note that out of desparation I've added this section:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097150"/>
</system.web>
```

without any effect.

In the error log there is one more exception being thrown directly after starting up the service. I neither know what it means nor whether it is related to the problem at all:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException
>
> Content Type multipart/related;
>   type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0&gt;";boundary="uuid:b230e809-500b-4217-a08e-32ff49e13bac+id=5";start-info="text/xml"
>   was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client
>   and service bindings may be mismatched.

I've spent days getting this to work and really don't know what else I can try. I would be really really happy if somebody could have a look at the configs and maybe give a hint what else to try. So, the question is:

**What could be the cause for the transfer to fail and what can I do to solve this?**

I would also be happy for further advice on

**What to do to find the root problem here, if it cannot be identified based on the information given in the question?**

Appendix: I don't think the client side exception is of any use but I would like to include it in the question to make it easier for others with the same problem to find the answers to come (hopefully):

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host

Comment: I'm perplexed by your service config file. Shouldn't there be a `Services` node under `system.ServiceModel`?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you so much for looking at this huge question. I am not really familiar with this WCF thing, but I think the config doesn't need this because the service is hosted in an Azure WebRole and the role takes care of this. I might be wrong though. Am I missing something although this is hosted in a WebRole?

Comment: Sorry I can't help Marc, I'm not really an Azure guy.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see where the service binding is being specified in the serivce config file. I suspect that the configuration values are not being read and this to be the cause of why.

So I propose specifying the name of the binding in the service config file as `BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService` (same name used in the client config) and then adding the following under the `system.serviceModel` node of the configuration file:

```
<services>
  <service name="TransferService" >
    <endpoint 
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransferService"
        contract="Transfer.ITransferService" />
  </service>
</services>
```